# Silly RegEx issue. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, regex

```
String url = "hello world";

String p = "world";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    int start = matcher.start();
    int end = matcher.end();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How comes the if statement never gets hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `matches()` method attempts to match the entire string to the pattern.  You want the `find()` method.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you. I read the docs on Matcher and I'm still not clear on the differences between matches() and find(). Would you mind elaborating some?

Comment: match means "does the entire string match the pattern provided".          Find means "are there any occurrences of this pattern inside the string".

Comment: The comment should be: String p = ".*world.*"; // Reg Ex, not wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Matcher.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29). `Matcher.matches()` checks whether the whole string matches the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `find` because,

> matches tries to match the patten against the entire string and
>   implicitly add a ^ at the start and $ at the end of your pattern.

So your pattern is equivalent to "^world$".

Comment: ah...that makes sense...and is dumb. If i wanted that I would have added it. Urgh. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your pattern to `".*world.*"`:

```
String p = ".*world.*";
```

That way it'll match any string that contains "world".

Answer (score -1):

I experienced same problem. 
I don't know the reason. 
If someone knows problem please post here. 
I had solved problem with using find() repeatedly instead of matches().